# Sending email - where am I going wrong?

Tags: c#

I am trying to send an email, each time I call this method and try to send it, it throws an error of "Failure Sending Mail." It's not very descriptive, and i'm not sure of which point this is even failing since it goes through all of the code and seems okay about it.

The code:

```
public void SendEmail()
{
    private string localhost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    msg.To.Add(strUserEmail);

    //determine if the email sent was successful
    if (blnFlag == true)
    {
        msg.Subject = "File Move was successful";
    }
    else
    {
        msg.Subject = "File Move";
    }

    msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(GlobalVars.strFromEmail);
    msg.Body = strMessage;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(localhost);
    client.Send(msg);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to put breakpoints and debug?

Comment: Are you running a SMTP service on your machine?

Comment: Can you show us `localhost`?

Comment: @shree.pat18 yes, I stepped though the code and there was no major inicator of what's making the code throw an error.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert no, I am trying to just use local host instead of SMTP. I am not really familiar with setting up SMTP so I was hoping to just use local host

Comment: All localhost is, is the address 127.0.0.1 which resolves to your machine. You still need to run something for it to talk to...

Comment: You could try using the SMTP server provided by Gmail for testing to see if SMTP is the cause.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert I set up a variable where it is my machine name. What else would I need to set up?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I don't have gmail

Comment: it you point it at your machine you need a SMTP service otherwise you must point it at another machine that has it. Try: icloud.com, gmail.com, yahoo.com they all provide mail via SMTP.

Comment: how do you even go about setting up an SMTP service? It is not static of who is going to be usig this. There are a variety of users who will be sent emails when all is said and done so realistically that would not work what so ever. @AnthonyLambert

Comment: Well you won't be sending many mails without one will you?

Comment: @AnthonyLambert which is why I asked if you knew how to go about setting one up

Comment: @user3302467 Google it.

Comment: Millions of people who know very little about computers go to these websites and set up there mail every day. I'm sure you can put in some effort and do the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 client.EnableSsl = true;
 NetworkCredential crend = new NetworkCredential("SenderMailAddress","SenderPassword" );
 client.Credentials = crend;
```

and try catch send method - this is just common choise)